# Managing Gcal Response + express and header issue

Tags: api, express, calendar, pug

I'm new to node and banging my head against a wall on what should be a simple  node+express+googlecal+pug issue

- node/express route accepts requests and calls controller
- controller ensures validation of auth and then...
- executes a successful gcal function...console.log has the data i need
- trying to directly (in controller function) returns "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"....why is a call to Gcal API forcing a response back to client?
- Trying to make it more micro via individual calls to each function results in same result

What am I missing here?

```
  getcalendars: async function(oAuth2Client, res)   {
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth: oAuth2Client });

cal = await calendar.calendarList.list(
  {},
  (err, result) => {
    //console.log("HEADERS SENT1?: "+res.headersSent);
    if (err) {
    console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    return;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    message2 = JSON.stringify(result)


  res.render('schedules', {message2: message2})
  return
});
```

},

**EDIT: Calling function**

```
router.route('/dashboard/schedules')
.get(async function(req, res) {

  if (req.session.loggedin) {

          
//x =  gcalController.getcalendars(req, res);  
            token = await gcalController.gettoken(req, res);
            isAuth = await gcalController.calauth(token);
            listcalendars = await gcalController.getcalendars(isAuth,res);
      } else {
          res.redirect("/?error=failedAuthentication")
          //res.send('Please login to view this page!');
      }
      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Can't set headers already sent` happens when you're sending a response more than once. Usually you can terminate the function by returning your `res.send()` call.

It looks like the express middleware that created the `res` object is sending a response by the time your `res.render()` gets pulled out of the microtask queue.

Can you show the full code? It seems that this is probably originating in the scope where `getcalendars` is called.

Comment: the originating call is: 



router.route('/dashboard/schedules')
.get(async function(req, res) {

  if (req.session.loggedin) {
            token = await gcalController.gettoken(req, res);
            isAuth = await gcalController.calauth(token);
            listcalendars = await gcalController.getcalendars(isAuth,res);
      } else {
          res.redirect("/?error=failedAuthentication")
          //res.send('Please login to view this page!');
      }
      res.end();
});

Comment: You're passing the same req/res to `token = await gcalController.gettoken(req, res);`. Could it be that a response is sent from that call?